# Select result in grouped row using fetch and while in PHP

Tags: php, sql

In the code below, I send a request, the I put the result In a table using PDO fetch. But when we have a "Data Element" with 2 elements, it creates 2 rows in the table, 1 for each "element". Example:

```
****************************************
**Data Element Name** | data 1
****************************************
**Elements**          | element 1
****************************************

****************************************
**Data Element Name** | data 1
****************************************
**Elements**          | element 2
****************************************
and what I want is:
****************************************
**Data Element Name** | data 1
****************************************
**Elements**          |element 1
                      |element 2
****************************************
```

Thank you!

```
<?php
if ($select=="Data Element Name"){
 $result="SELECT    
      D1.Data_Element_Name dataElementName,
      D2.Data_Element_Name element
     FROM 
      data_element_name D1
      LEFT JOIN packagedelement ON packagedelement.id=COALESCE(D1.base_Attribute, D1.base_Class)
      LEFT JOIN ownedattribute ON ownedattribute.FK_packagedElement=packagedelement.PrimaryKey
      LEFT JOIN data_element_name D2 ON D2.base_Attribute=ownedattribute.id
          WHERE 
      D1.Data_Element_Name LIKE '%$search%' ";

     try {
    $req =$pdo->query($result);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "An Error occured!"; //user friendly message
    some_logging_function($ex->getMessage());
}
    echo 'Data Elements including the keyword: " '.$search.' " ';
    echo '<table id="table1" style="margin-left:10px; width:700px;">';
    //Loop to stock results on an array
    $i=0;
    while($data = $req->fetch())
    { 
    $array[$i]=$data['dataElementName'];
    $element[$i]=$data['element'];
    echo '<tr>
        <td>
                <a href="" onclick="var source = ($(\'#arrow'.$i.'\').attr(\'src\') === \'img/arrowInactive.jpg\') ? \'img/arrowActive.jpg\' : \'img/arrowInactive.jpg\'; $(\'#arrow'.$i.'\').attr(\'src\', source); $(\'#hiddenDiv'.$i.'\').toggle(); return false;">
          <img id="arrow'.$i.'" src="img/arrowInactive.jpg" alt="arrowInactive" />' .json_encode($array[$i]). 
        '</a>
        </td>
               </tr>
          <tr id="hiddenDiv'.$i.'" style="padding-left:20px;display:none">
        <td>
          <table>    
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="LeftCell">Elements</td>
                <td id="elements">'.json_encode($element[$i]).'</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
          </tr>';
    $i=$i+1;
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: It's better to maintain different tables for data element name and elements. So that it will be easy to query

Comment: This is impossible because they are both element from the same class with same attributes(class associated to itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

First, as you walk thru result, watch primary key and build second dimension (store rows in temporary array) until key changes. When it does, you have one logical row processed and stored in that temporary array. Something like this:

```
$last_id = null;
$result = array();
while (($row = fetch())) {
   if ($row['id'] != $last_id) {
       // do something with $result
       $result = array();
       $last_id = $row['id'];
   }
   $result[] = $row;
}
```

Second option is to perform two queries at once and retrieve data from both simultaneously. First query is grouped by primary key without left joins, second is select from previously left joined tables. Both queries must be sorted in the same way. You fetch one row from the first query and then fetch all queries with the same primary key from second query. Just the same way as merge sort works. It can help when you have big results, but usually you can stick with the first variant.

Comment: You initialize $result before and within the while, is it a mistake?

Comment: The code is correct. But the first initialization (before while) is optional, since `$row['id']` is never null, so `if` body is evaluated always in the first iteration.